# update python 2.7 in place?

Tags: python, python-2.7, updates

A linux system has /usr/local/bin/python2.7 installed with a time stamp from August 2014. "python2.7 --version" says just "Python 2.7".  There are many packages installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Is there a way to update this in place to 2.7.14 that will not break the existing installed site-packages?  (Searched for the answer but if it was there it was well and truly buried under all the threads about migrating 2.7.x to 3.x.)

Thanks.

Comment: It's very likely that it won't cause any trouble if you just update from 2.7.x to 2.7.14 because the releases should only contain bugfixes and security related changes. The API and ABI should stay the same for Python versions with the same major and minor version number (although accidental breaks do happen).

Comment: The mechanics are part of the question - exactly how should such an update be done?  Consider the usual sort of linux install: unpack, ./configure, make, make install.  Part of "make install" will normally create a new site-packages directory and drop a few files in it, and there is a possibility it will stomp on the existing one when doing so.

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted it as a comment (because it just addresses a minor part of the question). Just thought it might be useful for you to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try posting here https://serverfault.com/ there may be more relevant answers but I think that is the version that ships with Linux and I would not touch that. It is better to just run yum or apt-get install python. If you do yum update or apt-get update that should update Linux python version if it does need to be updated.

Comment: The python which shipped with linux (Centos 6.9) is in /usr/bin and is 2.6.6.  Its site packages are in /usr/lib, not /usr/local/lib.  The one in question was installed from source.

Comment: Correction, the system ones are in /usr/lib64.

Comment: @mathog yeah you are right sorry about that it flew right by me